# Class with private constructor and factory in scala?

Tags: java, scala

How do I implement a class with a private constructor, and a static create method in Scala?

Here is how I currently do it in Java:

```
public class Tree {
    private Node root;

    /** Private constructor */
    private Tree() {}

    public static Tree create(List<Data2D> data) {
        Tree tree = new Tree();
        return buildTree(tree, data);//do stuff to build tree
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The direct translation of what you wrote would look like

```
class Tree private () {
  private var root: Node = null
}
object Tree { 
  def create(data: List[Data2D]) = {
    val tree = new Tree()
    buildTree(tree,data)
    tree
  }
}
```

but this is a somewhat un-Scalaish way to approach the problem, since you are creating an uninitialized tree which is potentially unsafe to use, and passing it around to various other methods.  Instead, the more canonical code would have a rich (but hidden) constructor:

```
class Tree private (val root: Node) { }
object Tree {
  def create(data: List[Data2D]) = {
    new Tree( buildNodesFrom(data) )
  }
}
```

if it's possible to construct that way.  (Depends on the structure of `Node` in this case.  If `Node` must have references to the parent tree, then this is likely to either not work or be a lot more awkward.  If `Node` need not know, then this would be the preferred style.)

Comment: When you say that you can get uninitialized tree - notice that in java I never get it as such. Due to a private constructor the user is forced to use a factory. But in your first example - could I not just do: **var tree:Tree = new Tree()??** Also - I am not sure how the second example is different from 1st (sorry - but all this scala business looks gibberish to me still!!!)

Comment: @drozzy - It's not that the _user_ could get an uninitialized tree, it's that your _factory_ gets one.  You're on your own to set the vars right in every single case in the factory; the compiler can't help you.  The immutable approach favored in Scala tends to require you to have something that is not obviously broken at every step--until you've built all the pieces of a tree, even the factory can't generate one.  Anyway, in the first case the constructor is marked private, so no-one else can call `new Tree()`.  In the second case, it's also private but the factory must supply a root `Node`.

Comment: Ah! Great I got it. The "object" makes it a singleton, so in essence it makes that a factory. Then the class is the thing I will construct. Interesting - how can the two things (object, class) - have the same name "Tree"? Also - how come I can access the constructor of "class Tree" from my "object Tree"? Could I have accessed it from a class named something different, like "Tree2"?

Comment: @drozzy - Your object tree is what's called a companion object, which means that Scala knows it's to have access to private vars. If you called it `Tree2` that wouldn't work, though Scala lets you define the scope of privacy, so you could potentially put both into a package called `treeish` and then declare `private[treeish] var root...` and then anything in `treeish` could see and use the var. But fair warning--doing things like that change the bytecode so that the var is _actually_ public, you just can't see it. If you demand that the JVM (not just the language) protect you, keep to private.

Comment: Hm.. for some reason when I use the second form that you provided, I am not able to access the "root" from my "object Tree" methods.

Comment: Also, how do I construct it? When I try **val tree:Tree=Tree.create(data)** it does not work...

Comment: @drozzy - You will have to be more specific as to what's going wrong.  `Tree.create(data)` should work, and you should have access to `root` both ways.

Comment: Well, what I mean is that if I do it they you showed me the second time - I am not able to access the value of "root" inside my "create" function. I guess this is because create is "static" in "object Tree", while root is a member variable of "class Tree"

Comment: Works for me.  Try this code in the REPL: `object Test { class Priv private (val msg: String) { }; object Priv { def create(s: String) = new Priv(s); } }`.  Then figure out in what way what you're doing is different than this.  (For example, the compiler has to be able to see both the class and object at the same time--in the REPL I make sure it can by putting both in another object.)